# apa6 and biblatex produce an extra appendix page

Tags: biblatex, apa6

I'm using apa6 class with Biblatex.  In general things work well except for one thing.  I have a paper with just one appendix and after compiling produces the appendix page fine, but the following page has a "Appendix B" on a blank page that includes an asterisk.  How do I get it to not produce a blank "Appendix B" page?

MWE

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\shorttitle{short}
\nocite{sigfridsson}

\begin{document}
\appendix 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please prepare a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that illustrates the problem. With just the two snippets combined I don't see a superfluous page (I get another error which is unrelated, I guess, and stems from my not using the `apa6` class properly). Currently I cannot reproduce the problematic behaviour.

Comment: Just made changes to the code example.  What more to put in.  You would need a bib file too, I suppose.  Should I put in a sample bib file? Thanks.  First time using stackexchange.

Comment: Try `\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]`. Your document class seems to have trouble with starred versions of the sectioning commands, with `bibnumbered` we use the unstarred versions, which seems to work. (Note for future reference that an MWE should just be one section of code that we can copy and compile at once without further modifications.)

Comment: I have modified your code to be a proper MWE.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]
```

The class you use `apa6.cls` redefines the `\section` command for the `\appendix`. That happens in such a way that the starred version of the command (`\section*` thus) is killed off. So you can't properly use `\section*` in the appendix - it is fine to use it before the appendix, though.

With `heading=bibnumbered` `biblatex` uses `\section` instead of the starred `\section*`.